# Finding the numbers in a given range?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, numbers

kindly tel me the concept to write a Perl program behind this ?

```
167 GATCAAAATACTTGCTGGA 185
192 TAGTAGATAGATAGATAGTAGTAG 228
```

in a **fileA** i ve a range from `167 to 185` as given as above and also `192 to 228`

in another **fileB** i ve set of numbers

```
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 168 169 179 185 193 1000
```

now from the above set of numbers in file B, i need to find out which are the numbers present between the range of 167 to 185 and 
print those numbers in the output.

so, output will be `168,169,179,185, 193`

what will be the concept behind writing this program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', $file1  or die "unable to open '$file1' for reading :$!";
my @arr1 = ();
while(my $line = <$fh>){
 while($line =~ /(\d+).*?(\d+)/gs){
    push (@arr1, $1..$2);
 }
}
close($fh);
my @arr2 = qw/2 3 4 5 6 7 8 168 169 179 185 193 1000/;
my %hash;
@hash{@arr1} = ();
for my $num (@arr2){
print"$num is present in the list\n" if(exists $hash{$num});
}
```

**Output:**

```
168 is present in the list
169 is present in the list
179 is present in the list
185 is present in the list
193 is present in the list
```

Comment: thanku nikhil i ve got the answer but i ve many ranges in fileA. How can i c for various ranges?

Comment: If you have various ranges then you can include it as `@arr1 = (1..10, 167..185)`;

Answer (score 2):

If you have Perl-version 5.010 or greater you could try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my @arr1 = (167..185);
my @arr2 = qw/2 3 4 5 6 7 8 168 169 179 185 1000/;

for my $num (@arr2){
    say"$num is present in the list" if $num ~~ @arr1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

if you can use Ruby(1.9+)

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
fileA=File.read("fileA").split
s,e =  fileA[0] , fileA[-1]
fileB=File.read("fileB").split
puts fileB.select {|x| x >= s and x<=e }
```

output:

```
$ ruby myRange.rb
168
169
179
185
```